# Bash: -gt operator not working as expected

Tags: bash

I have the following script.

```
logs=(/non/existing/folder/*)
if [ ${#logs[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
logs2=$(du \
-h \
/var/www/html/logs/ \
| \
cut -f1 )
echo "logs: "$logs2""
else
    echo "No logs found"
fi
```

The problem is that -gt 0 is ignored. As the path does not exist, I expected No logs found to be returned as there would not be greater than 0 files in that folder. If I change -gt to 1 it works. But this breaks things when a folder exists and has only 1 file. It works if an existing folder has more than 1 file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When `/non/existing/folder/*` doesn't match any existing pathnames it stays as is. Enable nullglob (`shopt -s nullglob`) to change that behavior

Comment: Or an optional,  `failglob` if you want to have an error message and an exit status of 1.

Comment: Thank you @oguz ismail, seems that did the trick.